# Read name into string with spaces c++

Tags: c++

I have an input file something like this(with 1 space between things):

```
   name             year       game/place
 Big John           1975     game1 2 game2 3
 Jacob Rafael Ben   1975     game1 2 game2 3 game4 1
 ....
```

I try to read this into a struct like this:

```
struct Contestant{
    string name;
    int year;
};
```

Here is the other struct for the games:

```
struct Result{
    string raceName;
    int place;
};
```

This is what i do in the next() func:

```
void next(){
    string line;
    getline(_f, line);
    _end = _f.fail();
    if(!_end){
        istringstream is(line);
        is >> _cur.name >> _cur.year;
        Result tmp;
        while (is >> tmp.raceName >> tmp.place){
            if (tmp.place == 1){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All i want here is to read the whole name with spaces into _cur.name

```
 Contestant _cur;
```

Comment: Looks like you ought to be using `getline`.

Comment: @Eljay That, and the real tricky thing is to read both `Big John` and `Jacob Rafael Ben` into `_cur.name` equally well.